# xargs with grep passes an empty string

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

Where does `grep: : No such file or directory` come from when I pass a filename to grep with xargs?

```
⋊> ~/.v/bundle find . -name config | grep ".git" | xargs grep "url" {}                                                                                11:07:46
grep: : No such file or directory
./Dockerfile.vim/.git/config:   url = https://github.com/ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim.git
./nerdcommenter/.git/config:    url = https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter.git
```

Though there are no empty lines or something like that when I do

```
⋊> ~/.v/bundle find . -name config | grep ".git"                                                                                                      11:08:30
./Dockerfile.vim/.git/config
./nerdcommenter/.git/config
```

And how to avoid it?

I know that I can skip the first line with something like `awk 'NR>1'` but would like to understand the cause of the issue.

Thank you.

P.S. I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add `{}` (unlike `find -exec`)

```
~/.v/bundle find . -name config | grep ".git" | xargs grep "url"
```

should work.

Or even better (just in case of file or directory names containing spaces or unusual characters) :

```
~/.v/bundle find . -name config -print0 | grep -z ".git" | xargs --null grep "url"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say what is going wrong on your site. I've tried to reproduce the error, having `.vim/bundle` as well, but I couldn't reproduce it.

Anyhow, I suggest to simplify the command to:

```
find . -wholename '*/.git/config' -exec grep -H url {} +
```

`xargs` is not required any more since `find` supports the `+` syntax. This is at least true for GNU, BSD (MacOS) and busybox versions of `find`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I like the idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I'm on mac. 

    ⋊> ~/.v/bundle find . -wholename '*/.git/config' -exec grep -H url {} +                                                                               20:31:23
    find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
    ⋊> ~/.v/bundle gfind . -wholename '*/.git/config' -exec grep -H url {} +                                                                              20:31:34
    gfind: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Strange! Then use `{} \;` instead of `{} +`

Comment: Nope. It returns `grep: : No such file or directory` for me.